# I am facing issue of "Specified rule does not allow auto generated coupons" while saving cart rules

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I am customising module where i want to save cart rule without **Use Auto Generation**. When i save cart rules its showing this error

```
Unable to save program with ID 37. Error: Error occurred when saving coupon: Specified rule does not allow auto generated coupons
```

Anyone have idea about this ?